# not an Ideal of F[x]

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field, and $R$ be the polynomial ring $F[x]$, and $f,g,d\in R$ be monic. Let $\Gamma=$ {monic $d\in R : d|f$ and $d|g$}. Show $\Gamma$ is not ideal, and it has a unique element of maximal degree: $gcd(f,g)$. I don't even know where to begin :(.

Comment: What makes a subset of a ring an *ideal*?  Can you state the definition?

Comment: Given $d_{1},d_{2}\in \Gamma, d_{1}+d_{2} \in \Gamma$ and $\forall r \in R, r\Gamma\in \Gamma$

Comment: Yes.  So, if I have some $d \in \Gamma$, then it's a monic polynomial that is a factor of both $f$ and $g$.  Can I scale it by any old polynomial $r \in R$ and still remain in $\Gamma$?  What if I take two common factors $d_1, d_2 \in \Gamma$?  Is it true that $d_1 + d_2 \in \Gamma$?

Comment: Is the zero polynomial "monic"? Unless you're willing to *define* it as such, $\;\Gamma\;$ is not even an abelian subgroup of $\;R\;$ , leave alone an ideal...

Answer (score -2):

First let $d \in R$ be an element of $R$ which is a divisor of $f$ and $g$. Now find an element $r$ in $R$ for which $d*r$ or $r*d$ is not in $\Gamma$.

Comment: This is a slightly weak answer but it is *not* incorrect. Why the downvote, people?